# Schizocoely and Enterocoely

Tags: evolution, embryology

In terms of phyla, mollusca, annelida and arthropoda are schizocoelic, whereas echinodermata and chordata are enterocoelic.

I know that their difference lies in the formation of the coelom but how exactly is enterocoely more advanced than schizocoely?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is "more advanced" than the other, they are separately evolved mechanisms to form a gut.

You may be misled by a human-centric view that treats humans and animals more humanlike as more advanced or "more evolved" than other animals but this is not true: all life has been evolving for the same length of time.